# Merge two strings

Tags: php

I have a string stored in my table. It's a number of values separated by pipe:

```
val 1|val2|val 44
```

I also have another string, separated by semi-colons that I would like to merge unique values from into the first sting.

```
abcd; efg; hijklmnop3; val2
```

So I thought that the easiest way would be to convert them into arrays, merge and keep unique and the implode back into the string.

```
(my loop) {
    $arr1 = array();
    $arr2 = array();
    $arr1[] = explode(';', $str1);
    $arr2[] = explode('|', $str2);
    $arr3 = implode("|",array_unique(array_merge($arr1,$arr2))); 
}
```

But when I try to

```
echo $arr3;
```

I get

> Warning: Array to string conversion

What am I missing here?

Comment: try use `print_r($arr3);`

Comment: Debug the line causing the error (`$arr3 = implode(…)`). Print the content of `array_unique(array_merge($arr1,$arr2))` and you'll understand.

Comment: `$arr1[] = explode(';', $str1);` is assigning the array result of the explode to the _first element_ of `$arr1`. You want `$arr1 = explode(';', $str1);` and you can get rid of the initialization as well.

Comment: Also, storing serialized strings inside the database is usually a sign of a poorly-normalized schema and will likely be a problem over time as you have to write bodge-y application code like this rather than simple queries.

Comment: If you read the error, you'd see it says "Array to string conversion", this means you're not trying to merge two strings, you're trying to merge an array and a string which is not possible.

Comment: @Sammitch All true, but I'm working with existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplify to following:

```
$str1 = 'abcd; efg; hijklmnop3; val2';
$str2 = 'val 1|val2|val 44 ';

// explode results an array
$arr1 = array_map('trim', explode(';', $str1));
$arr2 = array_map('trim', explode('|', $str2));

// Implode results a string
$string = implode("|", array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2)));

echo $string;
```

Results in

```
abcd|efg|hijklmnop3|val2|val 1|val 44
```

Note, that explode already returns an array. With the following you add an array to an array, but you just want the array.

`$arr1[] = explode(';', $str1);` is the same as `array_push($arr1, explode(';', $str1));`

The unique of your question failed, because you need to trim the spaces.

```
'val2' !== ' val2' <-- see the space
```